# How can I get the sum of child nodes from firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6

I am using Angular 6. I want to get the sum of child nodes from firebase.

[image]

```
this.x= this.af.object('inventory/product');

console.log(this.x.length);
```

Comment: what do you mean by sum? total number of documents in the collection?

Comment: yeh.. the total of childs. Here it is the number of products( 6)